# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value from NSMutableString

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I can't get around this error. When I run this function I get a fatal error. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
below is the function:

```
func changeSelectedFontColor(fontColor: UIColor) {

    let selectedRange : NSRange = self.textView.selectedRange

    var currentAttributesDict : NSDictionary = textView.textStorage.attributesAtIndex(selectedRange.location, effectiveRange: nil)

    var currentFont : UIFont = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSFontAttributeName) as UIFont

    let italFont = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia-Italic", size: 18.0)]

    var currentColor : UIColor = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSForegroundColorAttributeName) as UIColor

    var currentBGColor : UIColor = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName) as UIColor

    var currentUnderlinedText : UIFont = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName) as UIFont

    var currentparagraphStyle : NSMutableParagraphStyle = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName) as NSMutableParagraphStyle
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all lines like this:

```
var currentFont : UIFont = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSFontAttributeName) as UIFont
```

you are extracting a value from a dictionary and doing an explicit cast (to `UIFont` in this case).
All of these lines can fail for any of the following reasons:

- the specified key doesn't exist in the dictionary, so `objectForKey` returns `nil`, and the cast fails
- the value exists, but it's not of the type you are casting it to, so the cast fails

I don't how you are going to use all these variables, so I cannot provide a proper answer that best solves your problem.

However, you can get rid of the runtime exception by using an optional cast, replacing `as` with `as?`. Note that it will turn all the expression results into optionals, so for example in the line of code above, current font would be of `UIFont?` type:

```
var currentFont : UIFont? = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSFontAttributeName) as? UIFont
```

What to do with all these optional variables is up to you: you can use optional binding (but I expect a large number of nested `if`), or just use them as optionals, if possible.

Comment: I am building a Text Editor and am using these variables to  check to see if there are already some format changes to the selected text. if there is, I can add them to the current change. for example maybe the selected text is underlined and I later want to change the color of the text.  I need to check to see if the Underline property is set and then add it to the attributed string along with the new changes so all changes will persist.  I hope I explained the well enough.

Comment: In that case for each variable you should use [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_503) to check if a value is not nil, and do whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

ObjectForKey will return an optional, you should use as? to cast it to an optional and check its value.

```
let value = dict.objectForKey("hello") as? String
```

value is an optional and you can do

```
if value == nil {}
```

Or

```
if let value = dict.objectForKey("hello") as? String {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing for `nil`. `objectForKey(_:)` returns an optional which you force unwrap (by using `as`), so if `objectForKey(_:)` returns `nil`, then you crash.

You can either keep the values as optionals using `as?`

```
var currentColor: UIColor? currentAttributesDict[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] as? UIColor
```

or you can provide a default value using the `??` operator.

```
var currentColor: UIColor currentAttributesDict[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] as? UIColor ?? UIColor.blackColor()
```

NOTE: instead of using `objectForKey(_:)`, you can use `[]`. I think it reads better.